# Python, simple calculation

Tags: python

User types an integer number (smaller than 100, bigger than 0)
If user types 0, the program ends. In case of numbers that are 100 or bigger, or that are -1 or smaller, it shows INVALID, and prompts user to keep entering number.

```
a = int(input('Enter a number: '))

total =0 
keep = True

while keep:

    if a ==0:
        print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye')
        break;
    else:
        while a>99 or a <0:
            print('INVALID')
            a = int(input('Enter a number: '))

    total = total + a
    print(total)
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

Just putting normal numbers and getting the sum, I enter 0, then it stops, but when I enter 100, INVALID shows up, then I enter 0, the program doesn't end and it keeps showing me INVALID.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine on my machine...

Answer (score 0):

At your code, the else never breaks the loop so it only sums the total after it has exitted that 2nd loop, but that 2nd one doesn't have a behaviour for 0. You should try to keep it simple with just one loop.

```
total =0 
while True:
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if a == 0:
        print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye')
        break
    else:
        if a > 99 or a < 0: # You don't need a second while, just an if.
            print('INVALID')
        else:
            total = total + a
            print(total)
```

Identation is key at python, be careful with it.

Also cleaned a bit your code. As example: Since you get into a loop with the `while` there is no need to use 2-3 different inputs in and out of the loop, just add it once at the beginning inside of the loop.

Comment: Cool, something new to learn. I never heard of it before. Edit: Hm... interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more pythonic approach

```
total =0 

while True:
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if a == 0:
        break
    if a>99 or a <0:
            print('INVALID')
    else:
        total = total + a            

print(total)
print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye')
```

Answer (score 0):

When using your code, the result is :

```
Enter a number: 100
INVALID

Enter a number: 0
0

Enter a number: 0
Thanks for playing.. goodbye
```

And I think your code may should be:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number: '))

total =0 
keep = True

while keep:

    if a ==0:
        print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye')
        break;
    else:
        while a>99 or a <0:
            print('INVALID')
            a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
            if a ==0:
                print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye')
                break;

    total = total + a
    print(total)
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

You may procide your requirement more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are in while loop of else conditional since you entered 100 at first and you can't get out of there unless you enter a number satisfies 0 <= a <= 99. You can make another if statement for a == 0 to exit the while loop just below a = int(input('Enter a number')) of else conditional.

I think it is good to check where you are in while loop using just one print(a). For example, just before if-else conditional or just before while of else conditional. Then, you can check where it gets wrong.

```
a = int(input('Enter a number: '))

total = 0 
keep = True

while keep:
    \\ print(a) here to make sure if you are passing here or not.  
    if a == 0:
        print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye')
        break;
    else:
        \\ print(a) here to make sure if you are passing here or not. 
        while a > 99 or a < 0:   \\You are in while loop since you entered 100 at first and you can't get out from here unless you enter a: 0 <= a <= 99.
            print('INVALID')
            a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
            if a == 0: 
                print('Thanks for playing.. goodbye') 
                break;
    total = total + a
    print(total)
    a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```